# How to fix: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables when installing reaver 1.4

Tags: compiling

I want to install reaver-1.4 and after ./configure I get the code above.
Tried to fix it but no solution on other sites has worked for me

config.log says:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by reaver configure 1.4, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.65.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure CFLAGS=-O3

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = mk-s-zero
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.4.0-78-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2033: checking for gcc
configure:2049: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2060: result: gcc
configure:2289: checking for C compiler version
configure:2298: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2309: $? = 0
configure:2298: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
configure:2309: $? = 0
configure:2298: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2309: $? = 1
configure:2298: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2309: $? = 1
configure:2329: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2351: gcc -O3   conftest.c  >&5
/usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2355: $? = 1
configure:2393: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "reaver"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "reaver"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "reaver 1.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2398: error: in `/home/maynard/reaver-1.4/src':
configure:2402: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-O3
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

CC='gcc'
CFLAGS='-O3'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='reaver'
PACKAGE_STRING='reaver 1.4'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='reaver'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.4'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target=''
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "reaver"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "reaver"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.4"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "reaver 1.4"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Looks like you have an (incompatible) version of `ld` in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: If you give link to reaver, and tell what you ran, we can try to replicate. 

I am guessing you are missing some development software. Problem you mention can happen if you permissions dont allow gcc to write in folder.